# How to convert number into words using sql

Tags: oracle

I need to convert date into words using sql , is it possible

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (2, 'j'), 'jsp') FROM DUAL;
```

I want to know why are we using 'j' and 'jsp in this query.

Comment: The functions you're calling were intended to convert a number to a date, and a date to words; the side-effect is that this combination of steps by happy chance is useful for converting a certain range of numbers into words.

Comment: So - what do you need to convert, a **number** as you wrote in your title, or a **date** as you put in the question? Or do you think "number" and "date" are the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

The `TO_DATE (2, 'j')` converts the number "2" into an Oracle `DATE` datatype, using the Julian format. This gives you the date January, 02 4713 BC.

The `TO_CHAR( ..., 'jsp' )` converts that Julian date back to an integer and the "sp" means "spell out the number".

It seems the spelling-out isn't available unless you're converting a datetime to a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the inner most part of the query to_date(:number,'j') the ‘j’ or J is the Julian Date (January 1, 4713 BC), basically this date is been used for astronomical studies.

So to_date(:number,'j') it take the number represented by number and pretend it is a julian date, convert into a date.

If you pass 3 to number, so it will convert date to 3rd Jan 4713 BC, it means 3 is added to the Julian date.

Now to_char(to_date(:number,'j'),'jsp'), jsp = Now; take that date(to_date(:number,'j')) and spell the julian number it represents